# Why electric field at any point inside a charged shell is always zero?

Tags: electrostatics

We know that electric field at any point inside a charged shell is always zero since there is no charge inside the shell other than the periphery. But why is that?

Being curious I once tried to find out if it is really zero or not using coloumb's law.
I drew a circle considering origin as the centre. Then I marked total 20 points on the circle,  10 points on each side of the y-axis such that the other 10 points are exactly the image of them(each points ar representing negative charges). Then I took another point on the positive y-axis. Considered that a test object(positive charge) is placed on the y-axis. After calculating the electric field I found that the net electric field is acting towards the positive y-axis(0→∞). The reason behind taking circle is that I thought if infinite numbers of similar circles are taken to form a sphere(hollow) it would form a shell which I have imagined. So the field will increase rather than goimg towards zero.

Can someone explain whether I was correct or not in terms of the process I used?

Comment: Are you asking about electric field lines from a charge don't like to run into another charge of the same polarity and will tend to veer away from it instead? Because if you surround a point surrounded by charges of the same polarity, none of the field lines from them will want to go towards the other charges (i.e. inside) and will all point away instead.

Comment: What if the shell is negatively charged and the test charge is positively charged?

Comment: That's changing your initial scenario (or at least what I interpreted your initial scenario) which was just a shell of charges and nothing else, in which case, it won't be zero. To be honest, I am not sure what you mean by "We know that electric field at any point inside a charged shell is always zero since there is no charge inside the shell other than the periphery."

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that in the question

Comment: As far as I know according to Gauss, the shell does not enclose any charge so the electric field inside the shell at any point is zero

Comment: And by periphery I meant charges on the shell

Comment: *Why is that?* When you integrate, at any point inside, the field contributions (from Coulomb’s Law) due to every infinitesimal bit of charge on the spherical shell, you get a net field of zero.

Comment: Your initial statement that the "electric field at any point inside a charged shell is always zero since there is no charge inside the shell" is not correct. This is an ill-posed problems.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -3):

Alright...so firstly the electric field is zero only inside a charged **conducting** shell.Now,to the question as to why electric field must be zero inside a conductor,is because net charge cannot exist inside it.This is because in the influence of an external electric field(due to a positive charge let's say)towards right the positive charges inside the conductor shifts towards the right and the negative charges shift towards left..but this creates a very strong internal electric field inside the conductor(opposite to the direction of the external field) which in a very short time becomes equal to the external field and cancels it out.So, whatever charge you give the conductor from outside would just exist uniformly over the outer surface.SO, in electrostatic condition if a net charge was to exist inside a conductor would cause an electric field which would move some of charges...so its not possible.   Also..since you are talking about a shell it's essentially empty inside so charges can't possibly stay in an empty space.

Comment: *The electric field is zero only inside a charged conducting shell.* That’s not true. The electric field is zero inside a *nonconducting* shell with uniform surface charge density.

Comment: @G.Smith Only for a spherical shell.

Comment: Yes...if it's a non conducting shell electric field should be zero ...because charges cannot be present in empty space

Comment: @my2cts also true inside an infinitely long thin cylinder.